# Java (Spring Data JPA) not updating the updated_at field when I'm doing it explicitly

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-data-jpa, mysql-workbench

I've created a column named updated-at with DATETIME datatype, when I try to update it in using java.sql.Date like
`column.setUpdated_at(new java.sql.Date(currentDate.getTime()));`
It doesn't do anything even though there is no error on executing save().

Also tried the same thing using TIMESTAMP datatype in MySQL and java.sql.Timestamp in Java, no luck.

Comment: What's the output of `currentDate` ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, as you did not provide enough information. Please provide some more context and code.

If I had to quess based on the little information you gave, I would say, you did not open a Transaction or did not commit it.

In Spring you can use @Transactional annotation